# How to get byte[] from ReadOnlySpan<byte> without calling .ToArray?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Let's assume legacy APIs of type `public byte[] ProcessAndCreateNewArray(byte[] readonlyParam);`. If I have the input in format `var inputReadOnlyParam = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>` then without doing anything else, the API needs to be called like

```
// Could the creation of new array by calling .ToArray be avoided?
ReadOnlySpan<byte> res = (ReadOnlySpan<byte>)ProcessAndCreateNewArray(inputReadOnlyParam.ToArray())
```

But what would be a way to avoid the `.ToArray` call and pass in the buffer the span already holds? I tried to look at `MemoryMarshal`, but couldn't find anything. Is this possible?

Comment: You can't, because `byte[]` by definition must be a `byte[]` array object. You could potentially avoid the allocation by copying into a preassigned array buffer

Comment: I was thinking that maybe something like `(byte*)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref inputReadOnlyParam.GetPinnableReference())` could be used, but have to explore this further. :)

Comment: No because that only gets you a `byte*` pointer, which is definitely not the same as `byte[]`

Comment: Yes, I know. I was sloppy when writing that. Basically I think about going through the sources in GH to see if I could pin the span array (or internal pointer pointing to a beginning of a contiguous memory) and assign to something that can be wrapped into byte array (e.g. make its contiguous memory start from the same address).

Comment: Perhaps you could, but I really wouldn't advise it. It would be very dependent on the exact runtime you are using, and may change without warning